# JQuery get id after loaded html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem. I have two .html files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>...</head>
<body>
    <ul><li id="home"><a>Home</a></li></ul>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascripts/navigation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<div id="imgPanel" style="background:red;">
    <img src="Images/me.png" class="img-responsive img-rounded"> 
</div>
<div id="textPanel" style="background:blue;"></div>
```

In my navigation.js I load the second .html file into the "content"-div of the first .html:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $(".content");
    var a = $("#home");

    home();
    $('#textPanel').height( $('#imgPanel').height() );

    function home() {
        content.load("home.html");
    }

    a.on("click", function () {
        home();
    });
});
```

The loading works! My question is now:
How can I get the id of the div's of the second .html I loaded into the first one?
The `var = $("#textPanel");` is `null`.

Comment: yes it doesnt appear, but i use its height()-method as you can see. if i alert($("#textPanel").height()); it returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the content gets loaded asynchronously, you might want to change your code like this, to execute `$('#textPanel').height()` when it is available:

```
function home(){
    content.load("home.html", function(){
        $('#textPanel').height( $('#imgPanel').height() );
    });
}
```

From [this](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) specification of callbacks

**EDIT**

Alternative:

HTML of loaded content

```
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<div id="imgPanel" style="background:red;">
    <img src="Images/me.png" class="img-responsive img-rounded" onload="setHeight()"> 
</div>
<div id="textPanel" style="background:blue;"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $(".content");
    var a = $("#home");

    home();

    function home() {
        content.load("home.html");
    }

    a.on("click", function () {
        home();
    });
});

function setHeight(){
    $('#textPanel').height($('#imgPanel').height());
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! But why doesnt it changes the height on first load? Only after the second load he changes the height?

Comment: It would be helpful for other people viewing this question in the future if you add an explanation on how does your code solve the OP problem, for instance adding a brief explanation on the asynchronous aspect of jQuery's load function and that it accepts a function callback when it's completed.

Comment: But why does it changes the height after the click? not onload?

Comment: Maybe the height of the image in #imgPanel is 0 when it reaches the code the first time. You might want to set a timeout then also, to execute the code even later. Or, put an onload on the image with the function-call to set the height.

Comment: I added code for this alternative way, code is untested.